# Magento 2.1.4 command showing error when doing compile

Tags: magento2

I am getting generation does not exist error while compiling magento. My terminal log is below

```
[centos@ip-172-31-5-26 ~]$ cd /var/www/html/mage
[centos@ip-172-31-5-26 mage]$ sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Proxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% 1 sec 42.0 MiProxies code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 46.0 MiRepositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 46.0 MiB


  [RuntimeException]
  Source class "\ProductRepositoryInterface" for "ProductRepositoryInterfaceF
  actory" generation does not exist.

setup:di:compile
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Pls, try to clean folder var/generation and  then try again. maybe some files was broken and need to be sure that all is up to date